# Not equal operator for bash not working correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was writing a bash script to check whether the first word on each line 
is equal to a certain value but it isn't returning the expected values.

the bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 3 ]; then
echo "Error no file specified, default files will be considered"
a="input.txt"
b="correct.txt"
c="incorrect.txt"
while read -r line; do
d=( $line )
e=${d[0]}
if [ $e != "add" ] || [ $e != "sub" ] || [ $e != "addi" ] || [ $e != "lw" ] || [ $e != "sw" ]
then
echo "error"
else
echo "correct"
fi
done < "$a"
fi
```

the input.txt file:

```
ok lol no
right back go
why no right
sub send bye
```

The actual result is:
error
error
error
error

the expected result is:
error
error
error
correct

Comment: Unrelated: https://www.shellcheck.net/ has some diagnostics for you.

Comment: `$e` can't be 5 different things at the same time. Four of these conditions will always be true.

Comment: that is an *or* statement not *and*

Comment: Yes. That is tkausl's point. "true or false or true or true or true" will always be true.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: Not quite relevent, but use `[ $# -ne 3 ]` if you really mean to do integer comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if ! [[ "$e" =~ (add|sub|addi|lw|sw)$ ]];then
```

complete code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 3 ]; then
echo "Error no file specified, default files will be considered"
a="input.txt"
b="correct.txt"
c="incorrect.txt"
while read -r line; do
    d=( $line )
    e=${d[0]}
    if ! [[ "$e" =~ (add|sub|addi|lw|sw)$ ]];then
        echo "e[$e] - error"
    else
        echo "e[$e] - correct"
    fi
done < "$a"
fi
```

output:

```
> ./testInput.bash 
Error no file specified, default files will be considered
e[ok] - error
e[right] - error
e[why] - error
e[sub] - correct
```

Comment: yes it works correctly, I wonder what was wrong with my code.

Comment: the problem is what reported Tkausl and Amadan: logic OR will always answer with true, so you'll always have "error". if you try to change the OR with AND, you'll get your result.

Answer (score 1):

A `case` statement would be clearer.

```
case $e in
  add|sub|addi|lw|sw) echo "correct" ;;
  *) echo "error"
esac
```